# How to display reverse relation data in Django with unique title?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have 2 models and I want to display the data on my template, but currently, it's reflected with my other app. I have created the dynamic title and it's working fine on live but it's conflicting with other apps. Could you please help me here?

I want to display the data on `ListingTech` models, and a `ListingTech` models have multiple data of `Listing` so it should be displayed under the ListingTech model slug. A `ListingTech` model has multiple `Listing` so the `title and description` should be displayed of `ListingTech`.
It is working fine with the current code of the views.py file but it's giving an error whenever I try to access other app URL (Error is coming: `The view company.views.company_list didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`)
Please solve this issue, your help will be appreciated.

Here is my `models.py` file...

```
class ListingTech(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, default=None, related_name="ListTechCity", on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text=f"Value: Select City")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=None, help_text=f'Type: String, Values: Enter Company Name')
    slug= models.SlugField(max_length=60, unique=True, help_text=f'Type: String, Values: Enter Slug')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Meta Title", help_text=f"Values: Enter ListingTech Title.")
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Meta Description", null=True, blank=True, help_text=f'Values: Enter ListingTech Meta Description.')
    listing_img = models.ImageField(upload_to="listing-image", default=None, help_text=f"Enter Listing Image", verbose_name="Upload Image")
    overview=RichTextField(null=True, 
                        blank=True, 
                        verbose_name='Listing Overview',
                        help_text=f"Values: Enter Listing Overview")
```

here is another model

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,
                            verbose_name="Select City", 
                            related_name='ListingCIty', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text=f"Values: Select Company City")
    listing_technology = models.ForeignKey(ListingTech,
                                verbose_name="Select Listing For", 
                                related_name='ListingTechnology', on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text=f"Values: Select Company Technology")
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
                            verbose_name="Select Company", 
                            related_name='ListingCompany', on_delete=models.CASCADE, help_text=f"Values: Select Company")
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Company Page URL", help_text=f"Values: Enter Company Page URL")
    listing_overview = models.TextField(max_length=1500, null=True, blank=True, help_text=f'Values: Enter Listing Page Overview.')
```

here is my `urls.py` file...

```
re_path(r'^(?P<city_slug>[\w\-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)', views.company_list, name="company_list"),
```

here is my `views.py` file...

```
def company_list(request, city_slug, slug):
comp_list = Listing.objects.filter(listing_technology__city__slug = city_slug, listing_technology__slug=slug).select_related('company','listing_technology').order_by('-boosted_price')
for item in comp_list:
    if item.listing_technology.title and item.listing_technology.description  != '':
        title= item.listing_technology.title
        description = item.listing_technology.description
        template_name = 'company/list.html'
        context = {'comp_list':comp_list, 'title':title, 'description':description}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
    else:
        this_year = str(datetime.now().year)
        this_month = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%B')
        proj_prop = list(map(lambda x:"Top" + " " + x.listing_technology.name + " " + this_month + " " + this_year, comp_list))
        title = "".join(proj_prop[0])
        prop_desc = list(map(lambda x:x.listing_technology.city.city_name + " " +"Based Top" + " " + x.listing_technology.name + ". " + "Are you looking for the top" + " " + x.listing_technology.name + "" +", Here is the list of top" + " " + x.listing_technology.name, comp_list))
        description = "".join(prop_desc[0])
        template_name = 'company/list.html'
        context = {'comp_list':comp_list, 'title':title, 'description':description}
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: If `comp_list` is empty, your view returns nothing

Comment: @BrianDestura I know, but can you please optimize this views.py file, so  that it will not return the empty `comp_list`

Comment: If your filter does not return anything causing `comp_list` to be empty, what do you want to return instead?

Comment: let me explain it...`comp_list = ListingTech.objects.filter(city__slug = city_slug, slug=slug)`, can you now please confirm how many `Listing` of `Company` are added in this after checking my above `models.py` file